# str_replace the_title(); blues

Tags: posts, php

I have a dilemma, well a new blog which im developing and a few of the posts titles are like this 'Tutorial: Build your first App' or 'Tutorial: Start your business with xensuithia'

I have a page called tutorials that display the posts from this category.

I need the title to not display the 'Tutorial:' part on this page, I tried:

```
str_replace('Tutorial:',' ', the_title());
```

However it does not work. It just outputs the full title.

Comment: this is not a WordPress question at all. you need to do something like `$cut_title = str_replace('Tutorial:',' ', the_title()); echo $cut_title;` (I've flagged to close this question)

Comment: grrr - as Markus points out, it should be `get_the_title()`

Comment: Yeah, it is a WP question. It's about `the_title()` (and by inference, `get_the_title()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the_title() echoes the title. Use this instead:

```
echo str_replace( 'Tutorial: ', '', get_the_title() );
```

Comment: None of these work :'(

Comment: What's the problem exactly?